# Moment time difference in hours is not correct

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to find time difference in hours between two time but somehow its not correct. I might be doing something wrong but can't figure out where. The time difference I want is from a certain date with any time to some end date at 00:00:00

The following is how I find the difference:

```
async function getSubscriptionValidity(org_id) {
    // Get expiry date of the organisation
    let validity    = await Customers.findOne({ orgId: org_id }, "expiresOn -_id");
    let now         = moment();
    let expiryDate  = moment(validity.expiresOn).startOf("day");

    // Calculate time remaining to expiry in hours
    let difference = expiryDate.diff(now, "hours");

    console.log(now);
    console.log(expiryDate);
    console.log(difference);
}
```

**Result**

```
moment("2019-04-09T21:30:43.579") // Start Date and time
moment("2019-04-10T00:00:00.000") // End date and time
2 // Shouldn't this be 3 ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, moment#diff will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number, pass true as the third argument.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/